# How do I remove title and detail placeholder labels and its row from a table?

Tags: swift, xcode, ios10-today-widget

After much searching through the net (and Xcode), I haven't found any way of how to remove the title and detail placeholder labels and its containing row from a table view in a today widget. See picture below:

[Today Widget Interface Builder Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PYRT2.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Select the cell and change Style to `Custom`

Comment: To be sure we're talking the same thing: I'm talking about the 'row' (for want of a better word) that contains the 'title' and 'detail' words. I don't see the style option when clicking on those labels or their content view. Also, can the label contents be changed programatically? I need to change the detail text depending on a choice the user makes.